# Is it normal that I get NaN values after one-hot encoding?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, missing-data, one-hot-encoding

when I was doing preprocessing to my dataset, firstly I removed my dataset from NaN values.

```
fraud_detect = fraud_detect.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
fraud_detect.isna().sum()
```

After, I dropped some unnecessary columns.

```
remove = ['claim_number', 'claim_date' , 'claim_day_of_week']
fraud_detect= fraud_detect[fraud_detect.columns.difference(remove)]
```

For the next step, I did one-hot encoding. However, I saw some missing values occurred again after OHE.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
OHE=OneHotEncoder()
OHE_columns=fraud_detect[["gender","living_status","accident_site","channel","vehicle_category","vehicle_color"]]
OHE.fit(OHE_columns)
OHE.categories_


OHE_data=pd.DataFrame(OHE.transform(OHE_columns).toarray(), columns=['F', 'M','Own', 'Rent','Highway', 'Local', 'Parking Lot','Broker', 'Online', 'Phone','Compact', 'Large', 'Medium','black', 'blue', 'gray', 'other', 'red', 'silver', 'white'])
print(OHE_data)

ohe_final=pd.concat([fraud_detect.drop(["gender","living_status","accident_site","channel","vehicle_category","vehicle_color"],axis=1),OHE_data],axis=1)
print(ohe_final)

ohe_final.isna().sum()
```

Where is the problem, why I get NaN values after OHE although I removed them before?

[the output of NaN values after OHE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePOJI.png)

Comment: The `pd.concat` is a likely culprit, if your original data's index want a standard 1...n.